# BizTalk WCF LOB interface configuration

Tags: biztalk, wcf-binding, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to execute an oracle function and get back a result.
I have a question about configuring the send port.

I only have one action in the SOAP action header:

```
<BtsActionMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Operation Name="FUNCTION_AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE" Action="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/AMCCUST/Function/FUNCTION_AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE" />
</BtsActionMapping>
```

Do I need a separate action to get the result?

Should I set the pipelines to xml or pass through?

If I don't need a separate action is the name of the operation important? It has to match between the send port and the orchestration.

Is there a good reference for how this works?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need a separate action to get the result?

No

> Should I set the pipelines to xml or pass through?

XML

> If I don't need a separate action is the name of the operation important? It has to match between the send port and the orchestration.

You need to set the name of the Operation object in the logical send port to the same name as the BTSActionParameter in the WCF-Custom configuration of the physical send port. Be careful to set the "Operation" object name NOT the "Operation Message" object names!